# Regular expression to reverse character escape from software

Tags: regex, r, perl

I have a bibliography database file for use in LaTeX which is generated by the software Mendeley.

The software escapes all LaTeX characters such as \ % {} and so on. This is usually welcome, but I use a special package to display chemical molecules and this is where things go wrong.

The original expression `\ce{SnO2}` becomes `$\backslash$ce\{SnO2\}` in the file. The complete string looks like this:

```
title = {{Large scale F-doped $\backslash$ce\{SnO2\} coating on glass by spray pyrolysis}},
```

I would like to remove the whole `$\backslash$` and so on expression and restore the original`\ce{SnO2}`. 
I feel that this is a case for regular expressions, but is a bit above my head.

I am not terrible in using R and could run perl scripts as well but I was unable to come up with a solution. I know it is terrible practice not to provide any code, but I was hoping that this is a one-liner for someone knowledgeable in regular expressions

**EDIT**

Based on the answer given I came up with this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
 s/\$\\backslash\$([^\\]+)\\{([^\\]+)\\}/\\$1\{$2\}/g;
print $_;
}
```

Then in the windows command line I used

```
perl test.pl testing.bib > result.bib
```

which appears to work. testing.bib is the file that contains the unwanted characters and result.bib is, well, the result without those strings.

Comment: Is disabling the escaping behaviour in Mendeley's settings dialog an option? You can change this in the `BibTex` tab of the options.

Comment: @Marius no because it does 99% of the time what it should and I need the escaping for other stuff like math expressions

Comment: Ah, good script.  You can just use `print;` as the `$_` will be implied.  Just so you know, I used up today's allocation of back-slashes on this regex... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'title = {{Large scale F-doped $\backslash$ce\{SnO2\} coating on glass by spray pyrolysis}}';
$string =~ s/\$\\backslash\$([^\\]+)\\{([^\\]+)\\}/\\$1\{$2\}/g;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
title = {{Large scale F-doped \ce{SnO2} coating on glass by spray pyrolysis}}
```

As a one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 's/\$\\backslash\$([^\\]+)\\{([^\\]+)\\}/\\$1\{$2\}/g;print' inFile
```

The one-liner will create inFile.bak as a backup of your original file.

Answer (score 0):

Try a find an replace with this regex:

```
\Q$\backslash$\E
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PuDMEXlgJj0jN4y7)